# Clojure - recur applies to loop or let statement?

Tags: loops, recursion, clojure, let

I have a question in Clojure about recur. If I have a let-statement inside the loop, can the recur call be applying to the let statement instead of the values of the loop?
For example, in this scenario:

```
(defn someFunction [listA listB]
  ("do something here...." 
      [new-listA new-listB]))

(defn anotherFunction [listA listB]
  ("do something here...." 
      [new-listA new-listB]))

(defn myFunction [firstList secondList]
  (loop [list1 (someMutation firstList)
         list2 (someMutation secondList)]
    (if (= "true" (someCondition))
      (let [[newlist1 newlist2]
           (someFunction list1 list2)] 
        (recur newlist1 newlist2))
      (anotherFunction list1 list2) )))
```

is (recur newlist1 newlist2) applying to the loop or to the let?
And is there a way of skipping this let statement and calling recur directly with the two values returned by "someFunction", assuming that I can't change the fact that "someFunction" returns a vector with two arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`recur` always recurs to the closest `loop` or function, whichever is closer to the `recur` form. It does this by compiling to essentially a loop/jump statement that changes the values of the loop variables and then jumps back to the loop/fn point. This way it only uses one stack frame and can run full speed. This design has some intentional trade-offs:

- you cannot interleave nested loops
- recur can only be the last thing in an expression.
- there must be the same number of args to recur as loop/the-function

This last one requires that you keep the let expression or something equivalent such as a destructuring form. Loops do allow destructuring of the arguments just like functions:

```
 (loop [[a b] [1 2]]
    (println a b)
    (if (< a 10)
      (recur [(inc a) (inc b)])))
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 11
```

So you could write your loop expression to take the result of `someFunction` directly

```
(loop [[list1 list2] [(someMutation firstList) (someMutation secondList)]]
  ...
  (recur (someFunction ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

`let` is not a valid recur target.

You might be able able to set things up in the let to destructure the vector and therefore skip the let as well.

Also, an equoted `true` is a little odd. Is that under your control? If so, should just look for the boolean true and then can just say `(if (somecondition)...`